# Joining game through Steam - Invalid Password/Lost Connection

Tags: terraria

Getting these two random errors when trying to join a friend's server.

When I attempt to connect, it will say "Invalid Password", despite there being no prompt for a password.

When it doest prompt for a password it leads to "Lost Connection".

What's going on?

Comment: Try to and create a throw-away-character and try to join with it. It's just for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug which was [fixed in 1.3.0.3](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/1.3.0.3) on July 2nd.

> Fixed an issue where the password box would sometimes not show up.

There are a lot of other multiplayer issues, so I suspect your "lost connection" problem is also fixed, but there's nothing explicitly calling it out.